# can we update any .class file in the running war file in the wildfly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

can we update any .class file in the running war file in the wildfly?
so we need not redeploy the complete project for a single file change.
I have tried Deployment Overlays but it's not useful as per my requirement so please provide a solution other than Deployment Overlays.
We have one war file. and we need to provide a hotfix without redeploying war/ without deploying a new war.
The basic idea is to replace the class file at runtime. Does Wildfly provide any solution to support this requirement?
currently, I am using Wildfly-16

Comment: Can you deploy an exploded war file instead?  It's very unclear exactly how you would change a file within a war in the first place without copying the entire war file to the deployments directory.

Answer (score 1):

No, changing a class will require a reload of the deployment to updated the loaded code.